# how do you show all the files provided by a homebrew formula?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I wish to know the list of files that are provided (e.g. `libcaca`) to know if a given file will ba present (in that case, `` `/usr/local/cacaview ``)

how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to know what files are provided by a formula until you install it, but once installed, you can run

```
$ brew ls -v <formula>
```

to list all the files it provides.